# How to make an mbed print text from ascii codes

Tags: rs232, mbed

I want to send Ascii codes to an mbed and have it print Ascii characters which can be seen from Hyperterminal. How can this be done? I looked at the mbed website and found nothing about keyboard input or ascii characters.

Comment: Can you tell what the Hyperterminal is and what do you connect to your mbed to send text through it?

Comment: I think the mbed forums would be a suitable place to ask this question  as well http://mbed.org/forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC you can just use printf and scanf/gets on the serial ports of the mbed.

Comment: That's sort of right, but the text needs to be converted to ascii code before writing. Then when reading back they need to be converted back to text.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "text"? I do not understand what you want to do: most textual data today is actually encoded as a sequence of ASCII bytes.

Comment: I just mean normal characters.

Comment: Then I do not understand the need of conversion you are talking about. Could you provide some examples of what you have in mind?

Comment: +1 jpc is right; see [mbed "Serial Communication with a PC"](http://mbed.org/handbook/SerialPC) and [mbed Serial](http://mbed.org/handbook/Serial) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII printable characters are just bytes with values in the range of 32 to about 127. If your mbed receives ASCII, it should simply pass it to the output unchanged.

If it doesn't work, then the problem is in connection between mbed and whatever you want it to send text to.